# simple CNN model training using CIFAR-10 dataset STUCK at a low accuracy

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Hi i have just learned to implement NN models in pytorch through the udacity course and thus created a simple model with a a few CNN and FC layers. after much struggle i got the model to work. but it seems that it is stuck at the same loss even after repeated executions. i dont know where i am going wrong. Must be some logical error which i cant see.
Here is the code.

**model**

```
class cifar_clasify(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,16,3)
        self.BNorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16,32,3)
        self.BNorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*6*6,256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256,512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512,10)

        self.drop = nn.Dropout(p =0.2)

    def forward(self,x):


        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = F.max_pool2d(out,2)
        out = self.BNorm1(out)
        #print(out.shape)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = F.relu(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = F.max_pool2d(out,2)
        out = self.BNorm2(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = out.view(out.shape[0],-1)

        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.drop(F.relu(out))
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.drop(F.relu(out))
        final = F.log_softmax(F.relu(self.fc3(out)) , dim = 1)

        return final
```

**training code**

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)

model = cifar_clasify()
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr =0.03)

epoch =2 
step = 2
running_loss = 0
accuracy = 0 
print_every = 5

model.to(device)


for e in range(epoch):

    for inputs,label_ in zip(train_X,train_labels):

        step +=1
        inputs = inputs.view((-1,3,32,32))
        inputs,label_ = inputs.to(device) , label_.to(device)

        #inputs.cuda()
        #label.cuda()

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        logps = model.forward(inputs)

        loss = criterion(logps , label_.reshape(1))

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()


        if step % print_every == 0:
            test_loss = 0 
            accuracy = 0
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                for testx, lab in zip(test_X , test_labels):

                    testx = testx.view((-1,3,32,32))

                    testx,lab = testx.to(device) , lab.to(device)
                    lab = lab.reshape(1)
                    logps = model.forward(testx)
                    batch_loss = criterion(logps , lab)
                    #print(batch_loss.item())
                    test_loss += batch_loss.item()

                    ps = torch.exp(logps)

                    top_p , topclass = ps.topk(1,dim = 1)

                    equals = topclass == lab.view(*topclass.shape)

                    accuracy += torch.mean(torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor))).item()
            print(f"Epoch {e+1}/{epoch}.. "
                  f"Train loss: {running_loss/print_every:.3f}.. "
                  f"Test loss: {test_loss/len(test_X):.3f}.. "
                  f"Test accuracy: {accuracy/len(test_X):.3f}")
            running_loss = 0
            model.train()
```

Here is the result which i had to stop as it was not improving :

```
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 1.396.. Test loss: 5.288.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  5
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 3.038.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  10
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  15
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.669.. Test loss: 2.318.. Test accuracy: 0.105
step =  20
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 3.652.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  25
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  30
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  35
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  40
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  45
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  50
Epoch 1/2.. Train loss: 2.303.. Test loss: 2.303.. Test accuracy: 0.104
step =  55
```

Here is the code if you want any other information:

[Simple CNN for CIFAR 10 classification in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HPims3PDuwEPV-dDBmMdHxXCkO1sMkXj)

Comment: Try removing the batch norm layer. It estimates the mean and std of the dataset using the information within the batch, if the batch is too small it might estimate a wrong mean and std.

Comment: my next step was to train it in batches but in one of the comments i have mentioned the problem that occured while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since batch size is 1, use a lower learning rate like 1e-4 or increase the batch size.

I recommend making batch size 16 or larger though.

EDIT: To create a batch of data you can do something like this.

```
N = input.shape[0] #know the total size/samples in input
for i in range(n_epochs):
    # this is to shuffle data
    indices = torch.randperm(N)
    for idx in range(0, N, batch_size):
        batch_input = input[idx:idx+batch_size]   # this will get you input of size batch_size
        # do whatever you want with the batch_input
        # ....
```

Comment: hey i tried to make into batches using the command: `b_train_X, b_test_X = train_X.reshape((-1,64,3,32,32)), test_X.reshape((-1,64,3,32,32))` but its giving error `shape '[-1, 64, 3, 32, 32]' is invalid for input of size 6144000`

Comment: That means you cant split the dataset evenly into batches of 64. Either leave some samples out at the end or use another batch size.

Comment: How to decide what batch size to use so that all the data fits.? i tried with 40 and 80 and 20. same error is beign shown

Comment: ok i was doing a silly mistake i was trying to reshape the label to the same shape as dataset which is not true as the labels is of 1d for each sample. but having resolved that another problem has come and that is `multi-target not supported at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:15`

Comment: that error is also resolved using the following code `label_.reshape(-1)` the accuracy is roaming around 60% maybe its because of small batch or too simple model... anyway thanks!!

Comment: You can see pytorch's dataloader to read data in batches. or may be just use a for loop over the indexes

Comment: yes i tried that but how can i load dataset apart from cifar or mnist using pytorch's data loader?

Comment: I dont get it, is there something specific in dataloader about mnist/cifar?